# JavaScript not firing after Page Refresh or Paging

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, list-view

I'm using some JavaScript to manipulate a list view, such that the clicking of a button (provisioned through a calculated column), will redirect a user to another page. Based on the reference in another column along the same row.

The issue I'm having, is that the code works fine after initial page load/navigation to the list view. However, does not fire when paging occurs (I.e. have clicked through to the next set of 30 records), nor does it fire after a page refresh.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("SharePointBodyLoaded_TriggerEvent");

function SharePointBodyLoaded_TriggerEvent() {
    jQuery.event.trigger({
        type: "SharePointBodyLoaded",
        message: "loaded",
        time: new Date()
    });
}

jQuery(document).on("SharePointBodyLoaded", function () {
// Button redirect JS
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you not write same for page load?

Comment: post your Button redirect JS.. you do not need all this jQuery code..

Comment: where have you written in the page? Can you write the code inside master page and  test?

Comment: This is added in the PlaceHolderMain of the AllItems.aspx page